# Does the official length of a movie include the credits?

Tags: credits

When we see the description of a movie at databases such as IMDb and Letterboxd, does the available length contain the credits? What's considered the official length of a movie?

Comment: Letterboxd gets their running times from TheMoviesDB. Those times are self-supplied by the studio.

Comment: Just for context, in some movies there are post-credit scenes merely as a funny joke, but there are others where a post-credit scene can be relevant, like a sequel hook (showing the supposedly slayed monster stirring or opening its eyes). And yet others where important story is unfolding *during* the credits. A prominent example is WALL-E, where not watching the credits can make the ending darker, questioning whether the returned humans will survive at all, given the lack of resources, physical fitness, and survival skills. The animation during the credits reassures us that they do survive.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

IMDb defines the running time as per the description below. In brief, yes, the running time includes the entire credit sequence.

> The IMDb running times section records the duration in minutes of titles in the database. For theatrical releases the timing begins from the first distributor logo and ends at the last frame of the end credits. If there are any mid or post credits scenes, these should also be included in the running time. For TV-series we prefer to include the time without commercials, but we appreciate such timings are not always easily available so total running times may be submitted instead as long as the attribute (including commercials) is used.
>
> We prefer to list one single running time for all titles which corresponds to the default running time. This is the running time of the original release version in the country of origin and is indicated by an entry with a blank country field.
>
> <sub><sup>[IMDB - Running Times](https://help.imdb.com/article/contribution/titles/running-times/G8UMSUYEDCN3M2K8?ref_=helpart_nav_26#)</sup></sub>